# sort -u (unique) works for multi-keys but not for a single key

Tags: sort

Using GNU sort. I want to print only the first of a group of lines, based on duplicate key(s).

`-k1,2` works as expected – only the 1st sorted line is output

```
printf %s\\n 'a a c' 'a a b' 'a a a' | sort -u -k1,2 -t' '
# a a a
```

`-k1` does *not* work as expected – all 3 sorted lines are output

```
printf %s\\n 'a a c' 'a a b' 'a a a' | sort -u -k1 -t' '
# a a a
# a a b
# a a c
```

Is this normal for all variants of `sort`, or is it just GNU sort? 
It seems rather prone to *'unexpected results'*, as `man sort` shows the 2nd key number as *optional*: `-k, --key=POS1[,POS2]`

`-k1,1` does work with `-u`, wheras a plain sort (ie. no `-u`) works with just `-k1`.

Comment: I'm using sort (GNU coreutils) 8.21
and the manual says, when describing KEYDEF "... and the stop position defaults to the line's end", which appears to be what you are getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is POSIX default behavior as stated in [man page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1p/sort/):

> -k field_start[type][,field_end[type]]
>
> shall define a key field that begins at    field_start  and  ends  at  field_end  inclusive,
>          unless  field_start falls beyond the end of the line or after field_end, in which case the
>          key field is empty. A missing field_end shall mean the last character of the line.

Comment: This is the [POSIX standard behaviour](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1p/sort/).

Comment: @cjm, I added this to answer.

Comment: Thanks. If only I had read the next line after my quoted "`-k, --key=POS1[,POS2]`" manpage reference. It states, *"start a key at POS1 (origin 1), end it at POS2 (default end of line)"* - durr! :)